# List of already used objective-c Prefixes

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I'm looking to choose a namespace for a library I'm writing and I'd like to avoid conflicts with other namespaces.

Does anyone know of a website that lists all of the class prefixes in use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

https://cocoadev.github.io/ChooseYourOwnPrefix/ is probably your best bet. It's not "official", but it's a place a lot of devs would look.

In practice, as long as you don't use one that Apple uses, you'll probably be fine.

Comment: As bdrister says, as long as you don't use an Apple prefix, you won't run into many problems at all. With the iPhone, your app is sandboxed and won't load any dynamic/shared libraries, so you won't clash with other 3rd party apps.

Comment: Yes, I don't bother with prefixes at all for applications - only frameworks and plugins that are meant to be used by other apps

Comment: http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit/ - I've added VK to the list above.   Just wanted to make sure I wasn't stepping on an obvious library.

Comment: Unfortunately that list doesn't seem to be updated, as neither the Core Location (CL) or MapKit (MK) prefixes used by Apple are listed.

Comment: @JeremyP, no prefixes at all is a bad idea. A couple years ago, Apple shipped the Address Book framework containing a private internal class called 'Account'. Broke a whole bunch of apps that didn't even use AB (they got it indirectly by using another Apple lib that linked to it, I forgot which. The mail sheet, perhaps? ShareKit?)

Comment: @uliwitness  For what it's worth, now that Xcode automatically assumes I want a prefix, I just let it put them in.

Answer (score 11):

According to the Apple "Programming in Objective C" document of 2012-12-13, Apple reserves all 2 character prefixes for use in their frameworks. Users are encouraged to employ 3 character prefixes when naming their classes to avoid conflicts with Apple. See the "Conventions" section for details.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH10-SW2

Comment: Good hint, Xcode 5 already hints the *class prefix* field with `XYZ`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to initial-letters prefixes:

- If you're writing an application, use no prefix. You're unlikely to encounter another class named AppController in your app.
- Otherwise, use the product name as the prefix. For example, if you've written a color picker named “Whizbang”, name its principal class “WhizbangColorPicker”.

Comment: While I agreed with not using a prefix for application classes, it turns out some of Apple's private frameworks don't use class prefixes. Specifically, private framework MIME.framework which has a Message class and a few others.

Comment: Strongly disagree with avoiding prefixes for these reasons. Always prefix.

Comment: No prefixes at all is a bad idea. A couple years ago, Apple shipped the Address Book framework containing a private internal class called 'Account'. Broke a whole bunch of apps that didn't even use AB (they got it indirectly by using another Apple lib that linked to it, I forgot which. The mail sheet, perhaps? ShareKit?)

Answer (score 1):

"You should try to choose namesthat clearly associate each symbol with your framework. For example, consider
adding a short prefix to all external symbol names. Prefixes help differentiate the symbols in your framework
from those in other frameworks and libraries. They also make it clear to other developers which framework is
being used. Typical prefixes include the first couple of letters or an acronym of your framework name. For
example, functions in the Core Graphics framework use the prefix “CG”
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/BPFrameworks.pdf