# Does someone maintain a list with identifier prefixes used by C libraries?

Tags: c

Since `C` has no namespaces, we have to help ourselves with prefixes in non static identifiers. Any library seams to have it's own prefix. And if there are some collisions, things are getting ugly.

There are thousands of libraries with short prefixes, and I feel like that there are many I've never heard of.

So when I make my own library, how can I avoid collisions? Does someone maintain a list with prefixes that are already used by some libraries?

Comment: I doubt if there is a vaguely comprehensive list anywhere.

Comment: The C standard lists lots of things that are reserved, but it is unhelpfully scattered all over the document.

Comment: There aren't "thousands of libraries with short prefixes", there are probable hundreds of thousands. So compiling such a list is not really realistic.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it could be automated, by looking up header files in github repos with more than 100 stars.

Comment: And the chances of you needing two libraries in your project to solve two different problems, and they have the same prefix is likely to be small. And if they are distinct and does different things, even if they happen to have the same prefix, it's unlikely to have the same name after the prefix. The only problem is if you for some reason need to use two libraries for solving very *similar* problems, as then there's larger risk of both prefix and function name collisions.

Comment: @Cosinus There are probably as many libraries *not* on Github, that there are on it. So the list can never be complete anyway.

Comment: This answer to another question [List of already used objective-c Prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2738225/4142924) suggests referring this list at [https://cocoadev.github.io/ChooseYourOwnPrefix/](https://cocoadev.github.io/ChooseYourOwnPrefix/). And here is a short list of [Reserved Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html) from GNU.

Comment: The short answer is to pick a prefix and google your proposed function names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TL;DR; answer is that, other than for the Standard Library (where the list of reserved identifiers is defined) maintaining any such list would be (nigh on) impossible... even as a public Wiki.

For your own library, I suggest using a common prefix for all identifiers (eg `adb_xxx`... That way, you effectively define your own namespace `adb_`.

A good, consistent, naming convention should reduce the chances of a clash... as is the importance of maintaining the minimum scope (ie don't make things global unless they need to be).